# Impossible to connect to a PostgreSQL server after a new installation

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have installed postgresql on my new laptop (on Windows).

I see the service `postgresql-x64-11 - PostgreSQL Server 11` is running and is automatic. Perfect.

I have installed "dbeaver" (21.21). I would like to create my first database via dbeaver. I always get this message:

> Database postgres does not exist

[image]

Is it possible to create a database with dbeaver ? Or not ? Or must I do the creation with some command lines ?

Comment: Did you set password for user `postgres` after install? because default user have no password and should set password or connect without password to databaes

Comment: A new install of Postgres should have the `postgres` database in the cluster. Have you tried connecting using `psql`? What happens if you use `template1` instead of `postgres` for the database? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: I uninstalled completely postgres + dbeaver. I restarted. I re installed postgres + dbeaver. And now it works. I cannot explain what happened.